# Get a user’s ping in a python made Discord bot

Tags: python, bots, ping, discord

I’ve been trying to make the os ping function work, and it already workd but there is a problem:
If i type the command it gets the ping to google of the machine where the bot is located.
I think that a possible way to do this is making the os ping function execute in the user's machine when that specific user writes the command '&ping' instead of executing it on my pc (where the bot is hosted) so that user can see his actual ping.

If it's not possible please tell me why and how can i change the code to make the ping work

Thank you in advance

Here's the code i used:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('ping -n 1 ' + hostname, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

where hostname is google.com

PS = should i add information?

Comment: Your bot doesn't have the permission or the power to run arbitrary shell commands on other user's machines.

Comment: it doesn't run arbitrary, the user writes &ping and only then it does the ping. if someone knows how to get a user's ping please write it thank you

Comment: Your bot cannot know the latency of an end-user's connection to anything but itself. This isn't possible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer adam

Comment: Maybe if i get the user's ip, i can ping to him and get the latency from the bot to the user that wrote the command. Is it possible?